# Elastic search query to filter documents based on the top value of nested array

Tags: elasticsearch

The document has this structure:

```
{
   innerArray: [
      {set: "A", value: 123},
      {set: "A", value: 234},
      {set: "B", value: 115},
      {set: "C", value: 133},
      {set: "C", value: 256},
      ...
   ]
}
```

With a rather complex nested query, I can return documents where innerArray has elements both in *set* A and with *value* above a specified limit (e.g. 200). I can also order the inner_hits by value.

This query returns documents that have ANY inner_hits that match the criteria.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "innerArray",
                        "inner_hits": { 
                            "sort": { "innerArray.value": { "order": "asc" } }
                        },
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "filter": [
                                    { "term": { "innerArray.set": "A" }},
                                    { "range": { "innerArray.value" : { "gt": 200 } } }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I need only those where the FIRST inner_hit (filtered on 'set' and ordered by 'value') has a value above 200.
In pseudo SQL you could use a query with a HAVING clause but you could also write something like this:

```
select doc
from   documents 
where  (
       select min(value) 
       from   doc.innerArray 
       where  set = 'A'
       ) > 200
```

Is this feasible in elastic? How can I write such a query?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use [Nested aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation), a special single bucket aggregation that enables aggregating nested documents.

**Query:**

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "innerArray",
                        "inner_hits": { 
                            "sort": { "innerArray.value": { "order": "asc" } }
                        },
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "filter": [
                                    { "term": { "innerArray.set": "A" }},
                                    { "range": { "innerArray.value" : { "gt": 200 } } }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "resellers": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "innerArray"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "min_value": {
          "min": {
            "field": "innerArray.value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This just adds an aggregation that shows the min value, which btw already exists in inner_hits. I need to *filter* the returned documents based on that value, not just show it.

Comment: So in this case you should use top hit aggregation for more information check here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html

Comment: Perhaps I haven't been clear enough. Given these two documents, I want only Doc 1 in the results,  not both.

Doc 1:
`{ innerArray: [ {set: "B", value, 100}, {set: "A", value: 250} ]}`

Doc 2:
`{ innerArray: [ {set: "B", value, 100}, {set: "A", value: 100}, {set: "A", value: 300} ]}`

Only Doc 1 has a minimum value in set A that exceeds the limit of 200.